# Trying to find the big-O runtime of an algorithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

My friend told me about a sorting algorithm she designed that was intentionally bad. We were trying to figure out the big-O runtime, but we quickly realized it would be very difficult. We were, however, able to find a recurrence relation for the run-time to sort an array of size n:

$f(n) = 2*(2*f(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + f(n-2)) + 1 \\ \quad\quad = 4*f(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + 2*f(n-2) + 1, \quad\quad f(0) = 0, \quad f(1) = 0$

However, we have no idea how to turn this into a non-recursive function. Ultimately, we only need the big-O (or more strictly speaking, big-Theta) bounds on f(n). However, the master theorem definitely does not apply, as we are not dividing work into equal-sized portions. It also doesn't really fit any other sort of pattern that I know of for solving recurrence relations. Any help for solving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be dominated by the second term, i.e. $2 f(n - 2)$.

Thus we may define $g(n) = f(n) / 2^{n/2}$ and we will have: $$g(n) = 4\times g(n / 2)\times 2^{- n/4} + g(n - 2) + 2^{-n/2}.$$
Here I have omitted the $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ for simplicity.

Since the geometric series $\sum_n2^{-n/4}$ and $\sum_n2^{-n/2}$ converge, it is easy to show that the sequence $g(n)$ is bounded, and therefore we have $f(n) = \Theta(2^{n / 2})$.

Comment: Turned out to be pretty close to 25*2^(n/2) when I plotted it in Maple. Thanks for the help!